# Silverstripe i18n woes

Tags: php, internationalization, silverstripe

Having some insanely frustrating issues with the i18n _t() stuff in silverstripe.
(Im sure i had this working but now its not).

I currently have a php contact form that I need to translate to french. here is a snippet of my code from the php page. Editing the second argument shows changes in the displayed text, it just never seems to find the translation

```
public function generalContactForm() { 
    $fields = new FieldList( 
        new TextField('FirstName', '', _t('ContactUs.FirstName','FIRST NAME')), 
        new TextField('Surname', '', _t('ContactUs.Surname','Surname')), 
        new EmailField('Email', '', 'Email'), 
        new TextField('Phone', '', _t('ContactUs.Phone' ,'Phone No.')), 
        new TextField('Country', '', _t('ContactUs.Country','Country Of Origin')), 
        new TextareaField('Message', '', _t('ContactUs.Comments','COMMENTS'))
    ); 
    $actions = new FieldList( 
        new FormAction('submitGeneralForm', _t('Main.Submit','Submit')) 
    ); 
    return new Form($this, 'generalContactForm', $fields, $actions); 
}
```

Then I have my fr.yml in mysite/lang/fr.yml.(I have also tried fr_FR.yml as well).I have verified the integrity of the yaml file with an online validator and all good.

```
fr:
  Main:
    Submit: 'Submit TBT'
  ContactUs:
    FirstName: 'Prenom'
    Surname: 'Surname TBT' 
    Phone: 'Phone TBT'
    Country: 'Country TBT'
    Comments: 'Comments TBT'
    Response: 'Canned Response TBT'
    Company: 'Company TBT'
    Position: 'Position TBT'
    Website: 'Website TBT'
    Minimum: 'Minimin TBT'
    Maximum: 'Maximum TBT'
```

I have tried copying the lang folder to pretty much every imaginable location within the site structure including themes/name/lang and no luck as well as ensuring doing a flush=all after every move. Please help!

Comment: Wow. Thankfully I didn't spend too much longer on this. Even though according to Translatable my locale was fr_FR, my browser was still set to English. Fired up my Firefox browser which is in French and it worked. I feel like headbutting my desk

Comment: Maybe leave this here incase someone else is as dumb as me.

Comment: Does your site have more languages? What are you using? Fluent or Translatable? Did you set default locale and/or current locale somehow?

Comment: Your `_t` call should be the second argument to the Field constructors… the first argument is always the field-name and the second one is the title/label… no idea, why you have a blank string in there.